# Catching and throwing NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, android

I am working with an App that accesses the internet for some data, before sending any requests I check for Internet connectivity, if available the app goes ahead and sends the request, if not, it holds back. The issues comes in if when the request is sent and connectivity is lost, the app keeps on waiting for data if it takes long, it proceeds and tries to access data that is not available, in this case it tries access value of the "JSON" object"json.toString()", I get a NullPointerException. I have put up a try catch block but I do not know if its working perfectly, I want it to toast a message that "there was a network problem" when if runs in such a situation, if anyone knows how I can do this please share, below is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_id", postID));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");


            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    ADD_TO_CART, "POST", param);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Post Comment attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Comment Added!", json.toString());
                //finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Comment Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will catch a `JSONException` or a `NullPointerExeption`.

```
try{
     //Your Code

} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException npe){
      //Handle Exception
}
```

Comment: so in my case, I should specify the action I want it to take when it runs in that situation in the "NullPointerException" catch clause?

Comment: Yes, as you have mentioned, here you can toast the message "There was a network problem"

Answer (score 3):

Why catch the NPE? just check before dereferencing `json` if it is not null

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(ADD_TO_CART, "POST", param);
if (json != null) {
  //do current code
} else {
  showToaster("There was an error in the connection");
}
```

In general, catching Unchecked Exceptions is kind of pointless IMO since you can't recover from them, but specially with NPEs since you can so easily verify if the exception will happen or not

Comment: checking if json is null never works, I have even tried using junit's assertion, still I get a nullexception

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? what especifically doesn't work? checking for null does work

Comment: It fails to check for null, I do not know if it does or does not, but when I try that it gives me a nullpointerexception just there on the if statement, maybe I luck knowledge on that.

Comment: you get a NPE on the line `if (json != null) {` ??

Comment: Yes, I get NPE if I try Checking  if (json != null) {

Comment: i don't see how that is possible if you are indeed using java

Comment: I keep asking myself the same question, I do not know what really happens.

Comment: I agree with you HiliKus. Thank you for clarification. The answer provided was focused on the OP's question on catching a NPE.